# How to fetch all the child nodes of an XML using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdp>141100</gdp>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

How to pull all the child nodes of `country`?

For Example, I need the output as `['rank','year','gdp','neighbor']`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67598477/6243352) shows a general tree traversal that includes depth for printing using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use ElementTree lib to pull out the child nodes. This might help you.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
  print({x.tag for x in root.findall(child.tag+"/*")})
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("yourxml.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tag_names = {t.tag for t in root.findall('.//country/*')}

print(tag_names)  # print a set of unique tag names
```

The output:

```
{'gdp', 'rank', 'neighbor', 'year'}
```

---

- `'.//country/*'` - xpath expression to extract all child elements of node `country`

Answer (score 4):

[Have a look up to python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). It verily uses this xml tree as example.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

country = root[0].getchildren()
map(lambda e: e.tag, r)
# ['rank', 'year', 'gdp', 'neighbor', 'neighbor']
```

Btw, when you are stuck, open repl and go step by step. I do not remember all those stuff above. And last used xml parser 2 or 3 years ago. But I know, "try and see" is the best teacher.

Those are steps, how I come up with a solution.

```
# imports and other stuff.
>>> tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> country = root[0]
>>> dir(country)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_children', 'append', 'attrib', 'clear', 'copy', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterfind', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'remove', 'set', 'tag', 'tail', 'text']
>>> country.keys()
['name']
>>> country.getchildren()
[<Element 'rank' at 0x7f873cf53910>, <Element 'year' at 0x7f873cf539d0>, <Element 'gdp' at 0x7f873cf53a90>, <Element 'neighbor' at 0x7f873cf53c10>, <Element 'neighbor' at 0x7f873cf53c50>]
>>> country.getchildren()[0]
<Element 'rank' at 0x7f873cf53910>
>>> r = country.getchildren()[0]
>>> dir(r)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_children', 'append', 'attrib', 'clear', 'copy', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterfind', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'remove', 'set', 'tag', 'tail', 'text']
>>> r.tag
'rank'
>>> r = country.getchildren()[0]
>>> r
<Element 'rank' at 0x7f873cf53910>
>>> r = country.getchildren()
>>> r
[<Element 'rank' at 0x7f873cf53910>, <Element 'year' at 0x7f873cf539d0>, <Element 'gdp' at 0x7f873cf53a90>, <Element 'neighbor' at 0x7f873cf53c10>, <Element 'neighbor' at 0x7f873cf53c50>]
>>> map(lambda e: e.tag, r)
['rank', 'year', 'gdp', 'neighbor', 'neighbor']
```

Answer (score 1):

this code tested under python 3.6

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 name = '4.xml'
 tree = ET.parse(name)
 root = tree.getroot()
 ditresult =[]

 for child in root:
     for child1 in child:         
          ditresult.append(child1.tag)

  print (ditresult)

=============

['rank', 'year', 'gdp', 'neighbor', 'neighbor']
```

Comment: Also works in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with Python 2.7.12 and Gnome 3.18.2

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can do, with [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()

for country in root.findall('.//country/*'):
    print(country.tag)
    
# Alternative1 loop the country list of nodes

for country in root.findall('.//country'):
    for node in country:
        print(node.tag)

# Alternative 2 loop first child of root
for node in root[0]:
    print(node.tag)

# For all nodes use iter(), include the found node

for node in root.iter():
    print(node.tag)
```