# How to save the output of recursive function to list of items using yield and generator functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator, yield-from

I have the following XML file from this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm) as sample:

I have the following recursive function which prints output:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def perf_func(elem, func, level=0):
    func(elem,level)
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        perf_func(child, func, level+1)

def print_level(elem,level):
    print('-'*level+elem.tag)

elemList = ['description', 'episodes', 'movie', 'collection', 'stars', 'rating', 'year', 'type', 'format']

xmlTree = ET.parse('XML_file.xml')
```

The below line prints the result:

```
perf_func(xmlTree.getroot(), print_level)
```

Output:

```
collection
-movie
--type
--format
--year
--rating
--stars
--description
-movie
--type
--format
--year
--rating
--stars
--description
-movie
--type
```

I need to save the output to a list of items like below.

```
hierarchy = [collection, -movie, --format, --year, --rating, ... ]
```

So tried the below modification. But unable to get the result as list.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def perf_func(elem, func, level=0):
    func(elem,level)
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        yield from perf_func(child, func, level+1)

def print_level(elem,level):
    print ('-'*level+elem.tag)
```

I trying to modify the print_level() function to give some returnable output instead of printing it, but don't know how to do it.

```
perf_func(xmlTree.getroot(), print_level)

<generator object perf_func at 0x000001F6432BD2C8>
```

Changing the generator to list giving me the same output

```
list(perf_func(xmlTree.getroot(), print_level))
```

I checked similar questions in other links, but could'nt understand them much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in a function that uses `yield from` but never `yield`s any value. The generator needs to be populated with data at some point for it to do anything.

```
def perf_func(elem):
    yield elem

    for child in elem.getchildren():
        yield from perf_func(child)
```

You could use `yield func(elem, level)`, but passing a function into a generator is a somewhat odd pattern that inverts responsibility. The typical pattern for generators is to emit data lazily and let the caller apply arbitrary processing on each item inline, for example:

```
def traverse(elem, level=0):
    yield elem, level

    for child in elem.getchildren():
        yield from traverse(child, level + 1)

for elem, level in traverse(xmlTree.getroot()):
    print("-" * level + elem.tag) # or whatever else you want to do
```

---

In Python 3.9, `elem.getchildren` was [removed](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren), so here's the code that worked for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def traverse(elem, level=0):
    yield elem, level

    for child in elem:
        yield from traverse(child, level + 1)

for elem, level in traverse(ET.parse("country_data.xml").getroot()):
    print("  " * level + elem.tag) # or whatever else you want to do
```